# How do I do that '------- is a traitor' in GMOD?

Tags: garrys-mod

Ive seen many people be like '---- is a traitor' 'I'm with -----'

I can't for the life of me figure out how too do this? Do you look at somebody and press a key? Im new to GMOD so....

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you need to "bind keys".

Binding keys is the process of "binding" a function to a key, in other words, you specify a specific key, and then **what** you want to happen when you press that key.

## Suit Zoom

By binding the `Suit Zoom` button to a key, (which in HL2 actually zooms in your view), you can select what you want to say from a list of options.

To do this:

- Go to Options > Keyboard
- Find `Suit Zoom`
- Bind that to a key
- Click Apply

Now while in TTT you can click that key and it will open a menu and you can use the number keys at the top of your keyboard to use it.

## Binding Keys Manually

Use this if you want to specifically shout one thing, instead of a list of choices popping up.

To do this:

- Enable the *Developer Console* by going to Options > Keyboard > Advanced > Enable Developers Console
- Click Apply
- Click `~` key at the top left of your keyboard (you may have to hold it)
- type `bind *key* "ttt_radio *command*"`

A thing to remember is that the command itself, must be surrounded by `""` as shown.

Change `*key*` to whatever key you want.
If you don't know key names (for eg. KP_INS), then goto your keyboard menu, by doing the below:

- Goto Options > Keyboard
- Choose any random bind to replace.
- Replace it with your wanted key.
- Remember what the binded key is (it will show you, and in my case, it will say KP_INS)
- Replace it with the original key.

Then, all you have to do, is replace `*key*` in the console, with the remembered string.

**Command List** (replace `*command*` with these)

- `yes` - Yes.
- `no` - No.
- `help` - Help!
- `imwith` - I'm with *name of player you are looking at*.
- `see` - I see *name of player you are looking at*.
- `traitor` - *name of player you are looking at* is a traitor!
- `suspect` - *name of player you are looking at* acts suspicious.
- `check` - Anyone still alive?

[Source](http://ttt.badking.net/help/#TOC-Quickchat-radiocommand-keys)

Answer (score 0):

As I recall: it was <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd>, but that is just something I try to recall.

See the notes on the TTT help [here](http://ttt.badking.net/help#TOC-Quickchat-radiocommand-keys), but the help states that they're unbound by default, so you can bind them by using (for example):

> bind "v" "ttt_radio traitor"

Which types in chat when you press <kbd>V</kbd>: "(player you aim at) is the traitor!"

Comment: How do I bind them too a key?

Comment: You type 'bind "v" "ttt_radio traitor"' in the console (use the tidle key (~) to open the console ingame, it may be required that you need to enable the console in the options menu)